# How do I create a multi saved chart as .png?

Tags: arrays, numpy, charts

My goal is to save each plot after one pass of `for` loop. Here is what I've tried, but it shows the images overlapping. Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(10):
    y = arr_df[i].flatten()
    plt.title('Nitrat Graph')
    plt.xlabel('X Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
    plt.plot(x_axis, y, color='blue')
    plt.savefig(f'NO_{i}.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `y` is a one-dimensional array, all you need to do is add `plt.show()` in the loop and it'll display after each iteration. Here is an example replacing your data with random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
for i in range(10):
    y = np.random.rand(10,1)
    plt.title('Nitrat Graph')
    plt.xlabel('X Axis')
    plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
    plt.plot(y, color='blue')
    plt.savefig(f'NO_{i}.png')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: wow just adding a new line plt.show, Yo've Just Saved My Life !. Thank you......

Comment: @walikyuyudin Glad to help! Feel free to accept this as the answer ;)